# querying multiple indexes in elasticsearch and remove duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch

We have some documents indexed in two (or more than two) indexes in `elasticsearch`.

How can I get all the documents from the two indexes without duplication?

Comment: How do you define equality between documents?

Comment: I already know that some documents are indexed twice (or more) in different indexes. When the document is indexed in more than one index it takes the same id.

Comment: So, this means that the duplicate is not in the same index (this would mean same `_id` in the same index which is impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `_id` to be indexed and then use a `terms` aggregation.

The mapping change:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_id": {
        "store": true,
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
...
```

The query:

```
GET /test*/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The tricky part is with "get all the documents from the two indexes". Increasing the `size` from the `terms` aggregation will eat a lot of memory.